# Php artisan make:auth command is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, command

I'm trying to run this command in Laravel 5.2 but it's not working:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

And prompts with these statements:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
  Command "make:auth" is not defined
  Did you mean one of these?  


      make:test
      make:request
      make:migration
      make:seeder
      make:middleware
      make:controller
      make:provider
      make:policy
      make:event
      make:console
      make:job
      make:listener
      make:model
      make:command
```

Comment: their is nothing like use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticator; in AuthenticateUser.php.as i mentioned i'm using laravel 5.2

Comment: Have you tried to `composer update`?

Comment: yes just last night..

Comment: @YauheniPrakopchyk do you use laravel 5.2?

Comment: There must be any problem with your exist code, You must try with new fresh installation. https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation . Probably your would understand the exact problem.

Comment: Yes, I do use laravel 5.2. Tried fresh installation yesterday. Everything worked.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

**For Laravel >=6**

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan migrate
```

Reference : [Laravel Documentation for authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/authentication)

it looks you are not using Laravel 5.2, these are the available make commands in L5.2 and you are missing more than just the make:auth command

```
    make:auth           Scaffold basic login and registration views and routes
    make:console        Create a new Artisan command
    make:controller     Create a new controller class
    make:entity         Create a new entity.
    make:event          Create a new event class
    make:job            Create a new job class
    make:listener       Create a new event listener class
    make:middleware     Create a new middleware class
    make:migration      Create a new migration file
    make:model          Create a new Eloquent model class
    make:policy         Create a new policy class
    make:presenter      Create a new presenter.
    make:provider       Create a new service provider class
    make:repository     Create a new repository.
    make:request        Create a new form request class
    make:seeder         Create a new seeder class
    make:test           Create a new test class
    make:transformer    Create a new transformer.
```

Be sure you have this dependency in your composer.json file

```
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
```

Then run

```
    composer update
```

Comment: my mistake.sorry.I didn't checked my composr.json file.

Comment: This answer needs to be updated - Laravel is at 7.0 at the moment.

Comment: ***composer require laravel/ui*** doesn't work with me

Comment: Worked with Laravel 8.5. Thank you.

Comment: Tested on the Laravel 9.12.2 and works on it as well. Thanks!

Comment: But I don't to that without `npm`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 103):

**Update for Laravel 8**

`laravel/ui` still works but is considered legacy. Consider using [Laravel Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze) or [Laravel Jetstream](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-jetstream).

**Update for Laravel 6**

Now that Laravel 6 [is released](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-6) you need to install `laravel/ui`.

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

You can change `vue` with `react` or `bootstrap` if you use React or Bootstrap in your project (see [Using React](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend#using-react)).

And then you need to perform the migrations and compile the frontend

```
php artisan migrate
npm install && npm run dev
```

Source : [Laravel Documentation for authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/authentication)

> Want to get started fast? Install the laravel/ui Composer package and
> run php artisan ui vue --auth in a fresh Laravel application. After
> migrating your database, navigate your browser to
> http://your-app.test/register or any other URL that is assigned to
> your application. These commands will take care of scaffolding your
> entire authentication system!

Note: That's only if you want to use scaffolding, you can use the default User model and the Eloquent authentication driver.

Comment: Thanks. What if I don't want Vue, just the auth scaffolding?

Comment: @AmirAsyraf I would recommend to write it yourself, the `auth` middleware is native, you just need to write the routes then.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. After adding laravel/ui, the `ui:auth` command is available.

Comment: Thanks. What if I don't want Vue, just the auth scaffolding? use `php artisan ui:auth` check answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58449383/9978078

Comment: @Nino You have missed bootstrap parameter. like `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth`

Comment: @MahmoodJenami Thanks, you're right. I took the opportunity to mention this package is legacy with Laravel 8.

Comment: @MahmoodJenami Your suggested solution `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` not working, getting error `Command "ui" is not defined.`

Answer (score 80):

## In Laravel 6.0 make:auth no longer exists. [Read more here](https://medium.com/@panjeh/laravel-auth-routes-email-verification-reset-password-authentication-registration-routes-fb82b3337150)

## A- Shorthand:

**Update Nov 18th:**
Taylor just released Laravel Installer 2.3.0 added a new "--auth" flag to create a new project with the authentication scaffolding installed!

**To update laravel installer** [read here](https://medium.com/@panjeh/update-laravel-installer-8b9c5e1a2366)

It means we can do:

```
laravel new project --auth

cd project

php artisan migrate

npm install
npm run dev
```

Which is a shorthand of commands in the Section B. [Also read more here](https://medium.com/@panjeh/laravel-changes-in-php-artisan-ui-auth-php-artisan-make-auth-82fdb8893726)

---

## B - Details:

### Follow these **three steps**

**Step 1 -** First do this:

```
laravel new project

cd project

composer require laravel/ui --dev
```

**Note:**
Laravel UI Composer package is a new first-party package that extracts the UI portion of a Laravel project ( frontend scaffolding typically provided with previous releases of Laravel ) into a separate laravel/ui package. The separate package enables the Laravel team to update, develop and version UI scaffolding package separately from the primary framework and the main Laravel codebase.

**Step 2 -** Then do this:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
php artisan migrate
```

or

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan migrate
```

instead of

```
php artisan make:auth  ( which works for Laravel 5.8 and older versions )
```

**More Options** [here](https://medium.com/@panjeh/laravel-auth-routes-email-verification-reset-password-authentication-registration-routes-fb82b3337150)

```
php artisan ui:auth
```

The above command will generate only the auth routes, a HomeController, auth views, and a app.blade.php layout file.

You can also generate the views only with:

```
php artisan ui:auth --views
```

The console command will prompt you to confirm overwriting auth files if you've already run the command before.

```
// Generate basic scaffolding...
php artisan ui vue
php artisan ui react
```

and also:

```
// Generate login / registration scaffolding...
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan ui react --auth
```

**To see differences** [read this article](https://medium.com/@panjeh/laravel-changes-in-php-artisan-ui-auth-php-artisan-make-auth-82fdb8893726)

**Step 3 -** Then you need to do:

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

Comment: You're largely just duplicating @Nino's answer from a week ago.

Answer (score 15):

In the Laravel 6 application the `make:auth` command no longer exists.

Laravel UI is a new first-party package that extracts the UI portion of a Laravel project into a separate [laravel/ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui)  package. The separate package enables the Laravel team to iterate on the UI package separately from the main Laravel codebase.

You can install the `laravel/ui` package via composer:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

### The `ui:auth` Command

Besides the new ui command, the `laravel/ui` package comes with another command for generating the auth scaffolding:

```
php artisan ui:auth
```

If you run the `ui:auth` command, it will generate the auth routes, a **HomeController**, **auth views**, and a **app.blade.php** layout file.

---

If you want to generate the views alone, type the following command instead:

```
php artisan ui:auth --views
```

---

If you want to generate the auth scaffolding at the same time:

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan ui react --auth
```

`php artisan ui vue --auth` command will create all of the views you need for authentication and place them in the `resources/views/auth` directory

The `ui` command will also create a `resources/views/layouts` directory containing a base layout for your application. All of these views use the Bootstrap CSS framework, but you are free to customize them however you wish.

More detail follow. [laravel-news](https://laravel-news.com/running-make-auth-in-laravel-6) & [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#included-routing)

### Simply you've to follow this two-step.

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui:auth
```

Answer (score 7):

In short and precise, all you need to do is

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
```

`php artisan ui vue --auth` and then the **migrate** `php artisan migrate`.

**Just for an overview of Laravel Authentication**

Laravel Authentication facilities comes with **Guard** and **Providers**, **Guards** define how users are authenticated for each request whereas **Providers** define how users are retrieved from you persistent storage.

**Database Consideration -** By default Laravel includes an App\User Eloquent Model in your app directory.

**Auth Namespace -** App\Http\Controllers\Auth

**Controllers -** RegisterController, LoginController, ForgotPasswordController and ResetPasswordController, all names are meaningful and easy to understand!

**Routing -** Laravel/ui package provides a quick way to scaffold all the routes and views you need for authentication using a few simple commands (as mentioned in the start instead of **make:auth**).

You can disable any newly created controller, e. g. RegisterController and modify your route declaration like, Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
For further detail please look into the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication).

Answer (score 4):

This two commands work for me in my project

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
```

Then

```
php artisan ui:auth
```

Answer (score 3):

Checkout your laravel/framework version on your composer.json file,

If it's either "^6.0" or higher than "^5.9",

you have to use `php artisan ui:auth` instead of `php artisan make:auth`.

Before using that you have to install new dependencies by calling
`composer require laravel/ui --dev` in the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

**If you using >5 version of laravel then you will use.**

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev **or** composer require laravel/ui
```

**And then**

```
php artisan ui:auth
```

Answer (score 3):

> Please run the billow commands step by step in the case of laravel 9

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm install
npm install resolve-url-loader@^5.0.0 --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps
npm run dev
```

> Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel/breeze

```
composer require laravel/breeze --dev
```

then

```
php artisan breeze:install
```

then

```
npm install
```

you can check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits)

Answer (score 0):

**Following CLI commands are commonly used to setup Laravel 6.x, 7x , 8.x versions:**

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blade-example-app

cd blade-example-app

composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui bootstrap --auth

npm install && npm run dev

php artisan migrate

php artisan serve
```

Comment: koustav please add supported Laravel version in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh Laravel 6.x, 7x , 8.x

Answer (score 0):

**In Laravel 9**
I have followed the following steps and resloved this issue...

Make sure to create the project first and go to the project directory...

To get the UI and adding bootsrtap,

```
composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

Installl npm,

```
npm install
```

Run the npm,

```
npm run dev
```

Then migrate the tables,

```
php artisan migrate
```

Then Run the project, [Make sure to run the xamp and configure the Database]

```
php artisan serve
```