# why auth login view won't extend basic layouts

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-authentication

Laravel login auth view won't extends anymore 'layouts.app'.
Ive published auth config using this suggestion: [Php artisan make:auth command is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545641/php-artisan-makeauth-command-is-not-defined)

I'm on laravel 6.2.
And my views structure is this one:

[image: views structure]

'login.blade.php' contains :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
....
@endsection
```

'app.blade.php' contains:

```
    @yield('content')
```

So why my login page is now raw without anything from app.blade page? so no css, no header, no script etc...

Comment: `composer require laravel/ui` then `php artisan ui --auth`

Comment: @WahyuKristianto I did so!

Comment: You need to remove layout and views first.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto what u mean?

Comment: Try delete `layouts/app.blade.php` and `views/auth` before generate auth

Comment: @WahyuKristianto ok ill try, but views/auth was generated by the command above that u describe!

Comment: did... still raw...i try even config:clear view:clear cache:clear with no result

Comment: Is auth stub empty? Stub location `vendor/laravel/ui/src/Auth/bootstrap-stubs/auth`

Answer (score 0):

ok the problem is not how I describe in the question, but there is!

I just start from a fresh laravel install with: "`laravel new APPSOmething`"
then as described for version >=6 i run:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

and

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Then if u run the app u will find a page like this:
[image]

the probelm is not how ive supposed in extends layout (that works for the homepage)
but in 'layouts.app.blade.php" that now contains the wrong css and js file!!!!
so changing app.blade.php solve my problem!
thanks to all contributors and I hope that this can helps some other!

```
 <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

this need to be updated!