# php artisan make:auth not defined in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-authentication

I'm trying to run this command in Laravel 8.57.0 but it's not working:

```
PHP artisan make:auth
```

and the error is :

```
Command "make:auth" is not defined
  Did you mean one of these?  

      make:test
      make:request
      make:migration
      make:seeder
      make:middleware
      make:controller
      make:provider
      make:policy
      make:event
      make:console
      make:job
      make:listener
      make:model
      make:command
```

I also tried

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan migrate
```

but still have the same error. So, I guess that either I am using the wrong command or I am trying to do something that can not be done. 
Maybe most likely experienced people will see right away what is wrong.

Comment: try again after `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Try this : https://therichpost.com/laravel-8-auth-create-user-login-register-pages-part-1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you trying to do exactly? Create the authentication scaffolding from the `laravel/ui` package?

If so, then these two commands should be enough:

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

You can read further about it [here](https://github.com/laravel/ui).

Comment: I tried this, and work for me. Thank you, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

Since Laravel >= 6, the command `php artisan make:auth` was removed from the core and moved to an individual package called `laravel/ui`, so the command now looks like: `php artisan ui vue --auth`.

Depending on what you want to accomplish I can recommend you the following solutions:

1. Check this answer, this may be marked as duplicated: [php artisan make:auth command is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545641/php-artisan-makeauth-command-is-not-defined)
2. Run `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan optimize`
3. Try a different package, like [`Laravel Fortify`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using the fortify package for authentication?

```
composer require laravel/fortify
```

The details can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify).

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum)

composer require laravel/sanctum