# Command "make:auth" is not defined

Tags: php, laravel

I can't execute the this command but it's not working:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

And prompts with these statements:

```
Command "make:auth" is not defined.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545641/php-artisan-makeauth-command-is-not-defined

Comment: Make:auth is removed in Laravel 6, You need the package 'laravel/ui', The commands are different for this package