# Laravel 11 login system error: undefined method

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-11

Upon executing the commands `composer require laravel/ui` and `php artisan ui vue --auth`, Laravel throws an error. I have been searching for a solution but have yet to find one.

> Call to undefined method
> App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::middleware()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Php artisan make:auth command is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545641/php-artisan-makeauth-command-is-not-defined)